# gwt mvp contacts example project gives error when importing it in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

i downloaded the example GWT MVP Contacts project from

[google gwt mvp tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture)

and imported it in eclipse juno. when eclipse loaded it, i get the following error:
[image]

when i try to run this project the console gives me this error message:

> Loading modules
>      com.myproject.example.places.Contacts
>         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/myproject/example/places/Contacts.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
>   [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

before i downloaded this example project, i created my own project which i called "Contacts" too, but i deleted it from the workspace and after that i downloaded the gwt mvp Contacts example and imported it into eclipse.

What kind of error is this and how to remove it?

please help.

iam using eclipse juno and gwt 2.5 version

Comment: Try right-clicking the project > Build path > Configure Build Path...

Comment: ok and then? what i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

in your build file, under target "gwtc"
you may see the following like

this should be changed to proper values. Go to your src folder, under that you may find xxxx.gwt.xml file enclosed in a package something like com.google.gwt.sample.logexample. say inside this package you find the file LogExample.gwt.xml

your correct arg value should be

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse or similar IDE right click on project => Properties => Java Build Path, under Order and Export ensure all the entries are checked the errors should disappear

please refer to the image below:

[image]